# What does V.C. mean in this passage from Sherlock Holmes?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

I’d like to ask about the sentence from The Blanched Soldier by Conan Doyle.

> He was Colonel Emsworth's only son—Emsworth the Crimean **V.C.**—and he
>   had the fighting blood in him,

Can anyone tell me what this abbreviated V. C. represents? I couldn’t find a looks-relevant definition in my dictionary.  Is this “victory commander”, since it’s about army and war? Is the “victory commander” a fixed English expression in the first place? Is there any other options that seem to fit here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly, it stands for [Victoria Cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_Cross) the top military honor in Britain (and possibly some Commonwealth countries).

Comment: Why use the word 'almost'? 'Emsworth the Crimean V.C.' unquestionably means the person whose name is Emsworth (not a common name) whom the reader will of course know about because he won the Victoria Cross - which is very big deal indeed - in the (then) recent Crimean War.

Comment: @JeremyC, I'm influenced by the usage in random process theory where something being "almost certain" means that other outcomes are theoretically possible but have vanishingly low likelihood.

Answer (score 0):

As **The Photon** stated, V.C. as used by Doyle in the above, are most assuredly the initials for **The Victoria Cross** military medal of The U.K.

Comment: The wording doesn't suggest that -- more likely an office such as vice consul.

Comment: Respectfully, I have recently read some 1,700 pages of Sherlock Holmes, and I just entered your words into google. I reread the context and recalled the story of the two war buddies. The wording, in my humble opinion, is all about military service and seeing combat. Colonel Ensworth is the father of "The Blanched Soldier". The Brits have titles such as "Order of the British Empire" that they can be awarded, and one with such a title will have, following his name, O.B.E. (example: John W. Smith III O.B.E.) I do hope this information is helpful.

Comment: How do you explain “the ***Crimean*** V.C.?  “The Crimean Victoria Cross” doesn’t make sense to me.

Comment: To a British reader, Advent Jack’s understanding is obviously the correct one.  The British empire was at that time at its height and the Crimean War a relatively recent memory.  Military service in the officer class was one pathway to social success for the upper classes.   The V.C., the highest award for, therefore, exceptional gallantry, add a sexy frisson to the military rank.  “And he had fighting blood in him” makes it clear.  he had (his father’s) Elmsworth’s - the man that won the V.C, in the Crimean War - fighting blood in him.  Advent Jacks’s interpretation is obviously correct.

Comment: @Jim why not? Presumably he was awarded the VC for service in the Crimean war.

Comment: What is the purpose of repeating, without any elaboration, an answer that has already been given by somebody else?

Comment: @Jim Per Wikipedia 'The VC was introduced in Great Britain on 29 January 1856 by Queen Victoria to reward acts of valour during the Crimean War.'  Essentially it was invented for the Crimean War, and at the date of 1903 (when the story is set) it may well have seemed appropriate to distinguish one of those original 111 recipients from later recipients from wars in India, Africa and Afghanistan etc.

Comment: @Spagirl - I understand. It all makes sense circumstantially. The part I don’t get is the actual grammatical usage.  I did an ngram of “Crimean VC” - no results. I did an ngram of “*_ADJ VC” the only thing close was “Australian VC” which is entirely different.  To me giving him that title “The Crimean VC” is like saying “He was Laurence Olivier’s only son - Olivier, The Best Actor Emmy.- and he has the acting blood in him.

Comment: @Jim it would only really be like that if Olivier had been one of the first people ever awarded an Emmy and Emmies were instituted in recognition of the horrors of the acting profession and self-sacrifice required by it. And sorry if I'm being dim, where does ADJ come in?

Comment: @Jim also, I don't think he is being 'given a title' by the speaker so much as being distinguished from any other Emsworths of his co-locutor's acquaintance, such as the pig-fancier of Blandings Castle.

Comment: @Spagirl - I’m chalking this up to a BrE thing, that is apparently so unremarkable that no BrE speaker even sees it.  It sounds off to this AmE speaker, but so be it.

Comment: @Jim there may be no Ngram results, but there are plenty of general google search results, including https://fourthgarrideb.com/2015/10/30/the-victoria-cross-medal/ https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eM6LL8tlxJ0C&pg=PT486&lpg=PT486&dq=%22crimean+V.C.%22&source=bl&ots=sImRpWkeHk&sig=ACfU3U1zsS0V7xVWzrOc_nklTWeIJ8FUZw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj967fPnfTlAhWcTxUIHaJoBL04ChDoATACegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=%22crimean%20V.C.%22&f=false which may help reassure you that a) we really are sure its the medal, and b) I know my Emsworths

Comment: @Spagirl - I’m convinced it’s the medal.  I just haven’t wrapped my head around the usage “The Crimean VC” to mean “the Crimean War recipient of a Victoria Cross”  It’s some odd form of metonomy.

Comment: @Jim Ah, I see, at last! Thank you for your patience. Yes, I think it’s a dated construction but not one that poses an obstacle to British-English speakers.